# Which Authentication suits best for Azure Function app when exposing to third party

Tags: authentication, azure-active-directory, azure-functions

I am trying to understand which authentication suits good for Azure Function app because I have to expose function app end point to external team.

I have enable Azure AD authentication and planning to share App registration `client_id` and `client_secret` (endpoint oauth2/v2.0/token) where they will generate bearer token to Authenticate and consume my endpoint.

I was wondering if there is any other best approach of authentication than Azure-AD because I am exposing to external team.

Please assist, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

the most secure option is to request access tokens trough the [Azuthorization Grant Flow with PKCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-authorization-code). No secret is required, however if you need to use one, we recommend using [certificate credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-access-token-with-a-certificate-credential) which are asymmetric thus the exposure of the secret is more and better controlled.

You can also, configure [token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes) and enforce additional security measures trough [Conditional Access policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/overview). With them you can configure [session lifetimes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/howto-conditional-access-session-lifetime), require MFA for selected or all external users that access your application, that they authenticate from a compliant device, well known IP range or location, and more.

Also, and at the PAAS level, you can [Set up Azure App Service access restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions?toc=%2Fazure%2Fazure-functions%2Ftoc.json).